# Java Graphics setColor does not work

Tags: java, swing, canvas, graphics, awt

I am trying to implement a plot of a [Julia Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set) using a `Canvas` inside a `JFrame`. For some reason it seems that `setColor()` does not work. Here's the responsible code:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics aGraphics) 
{
    // store on screen graphics
    Graphics cScreenGraphics = aGraphics;
    // render on background image
    aGraphics = m_cBackGroundImage.getGraphics();

    for(int i = 0; i < m_iWidth; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m_iHeight; j++) 
        {
            int r = m_iPixelRed[i][j];
            int g = m_iPixelGreen[i][j];
            int b = m_iPixelBlue[i][j];
            aGraphics.setColor(new Color(r, g, b));
            aGraphics.drawRect(i, j, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    // rendering is done, draw background image to on screen graphics
    cScreenGraphics.drawImage(m_cBackGroundImage, 1, 1, null);
}
```

At first I suspected that the values were not passed to `m_iPixel...` correctly, so I hardcoded the values to `0xff` in the calling function. I checked this via `r`, `g`, `b` and am certain that they are all set to that value, yet the canvas is black.

The funny thing is: when I enter `aGraphics.setColor(Color.WHITE)` or `aGraphics.setColor(0xff, 0xff, 0xff)` instead of the variables `r`, `g`, `b` it works! Even though I checked the variables to be at the same value and hard coded them earlier to `0xff`. I am completely out of ideas as to what could be the issue...

**EDIT:**

The values were hardcoded as follows:

```
public void setPixelColour(int i, int j, int r, int g, int b)
{
    m_iPixelRed[i][j] = 0xff;
    m_iPixelGreen[i][j] = 0xff;
    m_iPixelBlue[i][j] = 0xff;
}
```

`setPixelColour` was called by the superclass in this method:

```
private void calcColour(int i, int j, int aIterations)
{
    m_cCanvas.setPixelColour(i, j, 0XFF, 0xff, 0XFF);
}
```

Which was in turn called by this loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < iCanvasHeight; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < iCanvasWidth; j++){
        cSum.setRe(m_cCoordPlane[i][j].getRe());
        cSum.setIm(m_cCoordPlane[i][j].getIm());
        m_iIterations[i][j] = 0;
        do{
            m_iIterations[i][j]++;
            cSum = cSum.square();
            cSum = cSum.add(m_cSummand);
            m_dAbsSqValues[i][j] = cSum.getAbsSq();
        }while((m_iIterations[i][j] < MAXITER) && (m_dAbsSqValues[i][j] < m_iDivergThresh));
        this.calcColour(i, j, m_iIterations[i][j]);
        m_cMsgIter = "x = " + i + " , y = " + j;
        this.repaint();
    }
}
```

I checked made sure that this loop is definitely completed. I checked the values again using the debugger right before `setColor()`. Since I don't trust the debugger (out of experience) I checked another time with the console by adding `System.out.println("r = " + Integer.toString(r) + " g = " + Integer.toString(g) + " b = " + Integer.toString(b));` right before `setColor()`.

**EDIT:**

This is my paint method of the `JFrame`:

```
public void paint(Graphics aGraphics) 
{
    Graphics cScreenGraphics = aGraphics;
    // render on background image
    aGraphics = m_cBackGroundImage.getGraphics();

    this.paintComponents(aGraphics);
    // drawString() calls are debug code only...
    aGraphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    aGraphics.drawString(m_cSMsg, 10, 450);
    aGraphics.drawString(m_cMsgIter, 10, 465);
    aGraphics.drawString(m_cMsgDivThresh, 10, 480);

    // rendering is done, draw background image to on screen graphics
    cScreenGraphics.drawImage(m_cBackGroundImage, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of how you checked the content of the variables? Or how you hardcoded them?

Comment: @Mr.M certainly, I edited the code above.

Comment: @Mr.M okay I have found the solution, yet not the reason for the error. When I change `this.repaint()` into `m_cCanvas.repaint()` (duh, obviously...) it works. Although this does not change the fact that `m_cCanvas::paint()` does getcalles with `r == 0xff, g == 0xff, b == 0xff`yet this does not change the screen's colour. Any idea how that is possible?

Comment: Alright, so I copied your code as far as I could and tried to see for myself. With the hardcoded version, I did get a white canvas though. Obviously I can't really test the other version. But I did not get a case where r, g and b had different values than were drawn to the screen. (Which leads me to believe the mistake must lie somewhere else)

Comment: You should consider using drawLine() instead of drawRect() to draw a single pixel.

Comment: @Mr.M hmm it seems so... I still couldn't find another mistake that might have caused this. Would you mind commenting the code that you used to test this?

Comment: @FredK I did, the reason I used `drawRect()` was so that I could increase the size of a pixel if needed. I stuck with it since I needed this once, but I don't think I'll need this now so you're absolutely right!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if posting big chunks of code in comments makes a whole lot of sense so here's my test code for you:

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        MyCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas();
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for(int i = 0; i < 800; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 600; j++)
            {
                canvas.setPixelColour(i, j, 0XFF, 0xff, 0XFF);
                canvas.repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the MyCanvas class:

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class MyCanvas extends java.awt.Canvas
{
    private BufferedImage m_cBackGroundImage;
    private int[][] m_iPixelRed, m_iPixelGreen, m_iPixelBlue;
    private int m_iWidth, m_iHeight;

    public MyCanvas()
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        m_iWidth = 800;
        m_iHeight = 600;
        m_cBackGroundImage = new BufferedImage(m_iWidth, m_iHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);     
        m_iPixelRed = new int[m_iWidth][m_iHeight];
        m_iPixelGreen = new int[m_iWidth][m_iHeight];
        m_iPixelBlue = new int[m_iWidth][m_iHeight];
    }

    public void paint(Graphics aGraphics) 
    {
        Graphics cScreenGraphics = aGraphics;

        aGraphics = m_cBackGroundImage.getGraphics();

        for(int i = 0; i < m_iWidth; i++) 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < m_iHeight; j++) 
            {
                int r = m_iPixelRed[i][j];
                int g = m_iPixelGreen[i][j];
                int b = m_iPixelBlue[i][j];
                aGraphics.setColor(new Color(r, g, b));
                aGraphics.drawRect(i, j, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        cScreenGraphics.drawImage(m_cBackGroundImage, 1, 1, null);
    }

    public void setPixelColour(int i, int j, int r, int g, int b)
    {
        m_iPixelRed[i][j] = r;
        m_iPixelGreen[i][j] = g;
        m_iPixelBlue[i][j] = b;
    }
}
```

I tried staying as close to what you provided as possible (even though your naming convention is not really my kind of thing). The main changes were in the loop in the main method because I didn't need most of that code. I also obliterated the calcColor method because it simply called a different method.

Anyway, this works for me (= I get a white canvas). I also tried changing the 0xff s to (int)(Math.random() * 255) which will result in a... let's go with rainbow-colored canvas, so it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can see that you did use `canvas.repaint()`, which I found solved the problem for me as well. When I accidentally called `this.repaint() from inside the extended `JFrame` class (which the nested for loop was inside of) the `canvas.paint()` method was called as well, with the RGB values set to `0xff`, yet the canvas did not change its colour. Calling `canvas.repaint()` solved the issue, but it still does not make sense that the canvas stayed the same colour, even though I was debugging inside of `canvas.paint()` with the correct arguments.

Comment: BTW, the I got used to the naming convention since at the company I work for it's the code guideline :) And I've come to think of it as quite nice and helpful. But we mostly use C/C++ for embedded projects.

Comment: What is "this" in this.repaint()? because if I call frame.repaint() it works all the same ;) That's how I started out, then I changed to canvas.repaint() to see if it still works and forgot to change it back ^^

Comment: Also: It's not like I don't realize why you name your variables the way you do, it's just that I feel like it always makes the code seem more complicated than it actually is ;) On another note: Why is m_cBackGroundImage m_c? m is for member but shouldn't c be for character?

Comment: I called `this.repaint()` because the method out of which `this.repaint()` was called was a method inside the class which extended `JFrame`, yet I should have called `canvas.repaint()`. it's `m_c`because we abused it for the c prefix for class types instead of primitives. Could be nicer, I know :)

Comment: Well like I said frame.repaint() works here as well so I see now reason why this.repaint() from inside a frame should not. Is it possible you made some changes to the paint() method of the frame?

Comment: Yes, I did. I added the paint method  to the question.

Comment: This is actually far more interesting than I initially thought. Turns out, the problem comes from mixing AWT and Swing. Do you need anything specific from the Canvas class? If not, try extending JPanel instead. Worked for me. Also: Since your JFrame's paint method will be theo nly one calling the JPanels paint method, you do not need double buffering in your JPanel (currently Canvas). Your JFrame already does that.

Comment: I don't think I do, I just want to paint pixels on it in a certain colour. I will try to use `JPanel`!